# Feeling impossible to leave for greater opportunity after taking a counteroffer earlier

Tags: job-offer, career-development, mistakes

A month ago I almost accidentally ended up in an interview which I took very relaxed not planning to get the job there at all (went just to get more interview experience). But they made me an ok offer I didn't expect to get. I felt a bit underpaied at my current place and could use the money, but I liked my current job much more compared to the offered one. So after some doubts I went to my boss and told about the situation. The next day my company countered the offer and I accepted.

Now a month later I got a great career boost opportunity I'd be very excited about a month ago, but now because of the whole situation I feel extremely stressed and obligated to decline this great offer, because otherwise I will feel like a complete "a****".

I don't know what to do: I feel like I already broke the trust with my current employer taking the counter (I know I've made a mistake), and leaving just a month after feels impossible because it will probably completely ruin my reputation as a reliable worker. But at the other hand this is not a common position and a great opportunity I might not get again for a long time.

Comment: Either leave or stay. It might be a somewhat uncomfortable situation, but we can't really make that decision for you.

Answer (score 8):

Well assuming you weren't required to sign anything as part of the counteroffer  committing you to remaining at your current employer for a specified time then you aren't obligated to remain there any more then you were before.

You're acceptance of the counteroffer might mean that leaving now will burn your bridges with that manager/company but it's not guaranteed to be the case. If the new offer is good enough that you'd be willing to pay that "price" for taking it then factor that in to your decision, and it is **your decision** regardless of what your current manager or any random stranger on the internet (including me) might think or say about it this is a choice only you can make, there is no gun to your head one way or the other.

Comment: Just because they counter-offered for you doesn't mean you owe them anything. Exactly. It means they value you enough to pay you more